# Random Header image on Page Refresh, CSS jquery javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, image, random, asp-classic

I need help finding code for my web page.  I have a "customize.css" page which has code for loading the header image.  But the header loads on a "header.asp", which is then loaded on the index page "default.asp".  I guess my question is what can I use to generate, one of four of the header images I have created, randomly on each page reload/refresh for a header?

This code is from my "customize.css" file.  After I get the code, what do I put in the "background-image:" for it to load to the page?

#header {
    color: #FFF;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: **WHAT DO I PUT IN HERE?**;
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

I have searched the net forum after forum for the past week in search of an answer but have yet to get one.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd go simple.  Define 4 different classes, each with a different background image.  In your header ASP script, select one of the 4 classes at random, and output that class into your code.  It's simple, the images will cache as they are displayed, and because you avoid JavaScript, it works for 100% of browsers/users.  For a small project, it's easy to maintain.

Now, if you get into 100 different background images, you would want to do something different.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?  Would you be able to give an example?

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak ASP.  Pseudocode (if you can call it that) is the best I can do for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It definitely seems like a few feet in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

See the random image header of this [page](http://ed.mauriciodenassau.edu.br/ead-nassau/)

I am using a specify class for change the background-position css property.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would create a separate web service to serve a random image. I would use PHP, but I assume you can do it in ASP).

```
#header { 
    background-image: url(/yourWebService.asp);
}
```

Have the service select one of the images at random, and return it accordingly.

Comment: Could you give me an example of doing this?

Comment: Not in asp, no. Care for a PHP Example?

Answer (score 0):

The only way of doing that in the css is by calling a URL that returns the random image. Something like:

```
#header { color: #FFF; height: 350px; background-color: transparent; background-image: "/loadimage"; background-position: left top; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

But then you must code a service at /loadimage that returns the image.

It will be much more easy change the image at the page load via javascript. Assuming you have the images img0.jpg, img1.jpg, img2.jpg and img3.jpg at the images directory, you could do:
You can do:

```
<body onload="document.body.background = '/images/img'+Math.floor(Math.random()*4)+'.jpg';" />
```